# How to take screenshot of debugged application in Android?

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, screenshot

If I have device montor running and additionally start a debug, then it suggests to close device monitor. So, I am unable to take screenshots with it. Is it possible to take screenshot of debugged application from withinn Android Studio debugger?

Comment: Android studio has option in DDMS . Where there is a Camera Icon. If you are debugging then this can be clicked to take current screen shot

Comment: Camera Icon entitled `Get Thread Dump`, very unsure it also takes screenshot.

Comment: Ah, found it in `Android Monitor` tab below

Comment: happy coding / screen shot

Answer (score 0):

Yes under Android Monitor there is options for both take screenshot and recording.[image]